# Can I run xamarin on windows 8.1 64 bit with visual studio 2015 enterprise?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Please help if any body can. I am searching for the last 3 days but could not find any solution. 
I first installed visual studio 2013 ultimate on Windows 7 32 bit,But no options for xamarin,Android and IOS were found.
Then I installed visual studio 2015 32 bit on windows 7 32 bit with 3 updates, and I installed with customized selection of "Cross platform mobile app development",after installation , When I created Android app project ,it was empty and gave me options to install xamarin. When I click on this option, it gave me option to upgrade installer when I click on it, Visual studio 2017 installer , started to install,after some time,it gave me customised installation options, I checked cross platform mobile app development,It get started to install, After some time,It gave error.
I tried many times.Same cycle is repeating.

Comment: You have to show some screen shots, like this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/#vs2015 so as to show what's wrong. Besides, if you do use Enterprise edition, your company should have Microsoft support contract which you can use to contact Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is just ***uninstall*** all of the copies of visual studio that you've setup so far, so that you can start afresh.

Then select and download the Community edition of [visual studio 2017 from this link.](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?utm_source=mscom&utm_campaign=msdocs)

When you install visual studio 2017, you need to make sure you select the following option in hte customisation section of the installation window.

[image: Screenshot from visual studio 2017 installer.]

It's worth also checking the "Individual components" tab and making sure that if there is an option called "Android emulator for visual studio" that it is also ticked, trust me it will save you a lot of trouble in the long room.

However If that option isn't there, then you don't need to worry about it.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this option and it worked fine.